# Two Applications with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have two applications in the following setup:

`/srv/http/myroot` -> main site

`/srv/http/myroot/myforum` -> Forum

`http://mywebsite` will succesfully navigate my Codeigniter site with no problems.

I want this: `http://mywebsite/forum`  to be rewritten to goto `/srv/http/myroot/myforum`

I can only access my forum software if this url is used: `http://mywebsite/myroot/myforum`

The forum that I am using has its own .htaccess and index.php. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following into your .htaccess

```
Alias /forum /srv/http/myroot/myforum
```

For more information, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: 500 Error when that is added anywhere in the generic .htaccess found [here](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite)

Comment: I solved this by adding this in apache configuration directly. If I added this in .htaccess directly, it would not work.